# How to refresh the key and value in cache after they are expired in Guava (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, guava, google-guava-cache

So, I was looking at caching methods in Java (Spring). And Guava looked like it would solve the purpose.

This is the usecase -

I query for some data from a remote service. Kind of configuration field for my application. This field will be used by every inbound request to my application. And it would be expensive to call the remote service everytime as it's kind of constant which changes periodically.

So, on the first request inbound to my application, when I call remote service, I would cache the value. I set an expiry time of this cache as 30 mins. After 30 mins when the cache is expired and there is a request to retrieve the key, I would like a callback or something to do the operation of calling the remote service and setting the cache and return the value for that key.

How can I do it in Guava cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i give a example how to use guava cache. If you want to handle `removal listener` then need to call `cleanUp`. Here i run a thread which one call clean up every 30 minutes.

```
import com.google.common.cache.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Component
public class Cache {

public static LoadingCache<String, String> REQUIRED_CACHE;

public Cache(){
    RemovalListener<String,String> REMOVAL_LISTENER = new RemovalListener<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<String, String> notification) {
            if(notification.getCause() == RemovalCause.EXPIRED){
                //do as per your requirement
            }
        }
    };

    CacheLoader<String,String> LOADER = new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String load(String key) throws Exception {
            return null; // return as per your requirement. if key value is not found
        }
    };

    REQUIRED_CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100000000)
            .expireAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .removalListener(REMOVAL_LISTENER)
            .build(LOADER);

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(()->{
        while (true) {
            REQUIRED_CACHE.cleanUp(); // need to call clean up for removal listener
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(30L);
        }
    });
}
}
```

put & get data:

```
Cache.REQUIRED_CACHE.get("key");
Cache.REQUIRED_CACHE.put("key","value");
```

Comment: So, ideally, I just want to get the cache. And somewhere in class Cache, is there any functionality where I can implement my method where I get the cache and then I put the cache there.

Comment: here i give example how to use guava cache

Comment: if you want to handle removal listener then i show how to handle it

Comment: Yeah. Can it be extended to a use-case where I just call `Cache.REQUIRED_CACHE.get("key");`. and if this key is not set in the cache yet, it does it in the class `Cache` ?

Comment: then you can set key in load method & return

Comment: Cool, I'll try this

Comment: From where is LoadingCache imported?

Comment: u wanted to use guava

Comment: yeah, I did that. But it doesn't import LoadingCache for some reasons

Comment: i used this :  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'   dependency

Comment: All other classes are working except for LoadingCache.

Comment: okay so I got the exception. 
` com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive load of: KeyName`

Comment: if you used this in spring boot app

Comment: then  u need to use @Component

Comment: without inject this constructor will not call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176883/discussion-between-sajib-and-nirvair).